# SQL Server Profiler - ApplicationName is "Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-profiler

I'm running profiler, trying to identify the source of one particular statement among a whole bunch of statements that occurred over a relatively short period of time. On one line, the event is `SP:StmtStarting` but the `ApplicationName` column is "Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio". Now, I know for sure that nobody was sitting at their workstation and ran this query. The `ObjectType` column is "20801- AQ", which is an "adhoc query". The `LoginName` is the name of the service account the SQL instance is running under.

So, what else, other than someone using SSMS running an adhoc query, could have been the source of this?

The query was of the form:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[table-name-here] 
    SELECT * 
    FROM [dbo].[table-name-here] option (maxdop 1)
```

Comment: Is this table user-defined or some system table?

Comment: I would install sp_whoisactive, run it and check how long it runs. Maybe someone run it and left.

Comment: its a user table with millions of rows

Comment: Could be an Add On or plugin to SSMS?